# How to close current stage when clicking a button to display new stage without making the components of the new stage inactive

Tags: java, events, javafx, stage

Let's say I have a `Stage` `A` which contain two `Button`s, `oui` `Button` opens a new `Stage` `B`, `non` closes `A`. what I'm trying to do is close `A` after clicking on `oui` `Button` and open `B`. I'm using `showAndWait()` to open `B`, then I try to execute `A.close()` which obviously fails being preceded by `showAndWait()`, when I tried to run `A.close()` before `showAndWait()` `A` closes, but then all `B`controls including `Button`s and `Text Field`s become inactive, is there any workaround ?

Here is the executed code when clicking on `oui` in order to open `B` `Stage` :

```
public class AController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button oui;
    @FXML
    private Button non;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO

    }

    @FXML
    private void ouiBtnClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("B.fxml"));

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    VBox mainPane = (VBox) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    stage.setResizable(false);


        stage.showAndWait();
        nonBtnClick(); // method that close `A`


    }

    @FXML
    private void nonBtnClick() {
        Stage s = (Stage) non.getScene().getWindow();
        s.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sedj601/SimpleLoginFx) should demonstrate what you are asking.

Comment: Also, what happens if you use `show` instead of `showAndWait`?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I used `show` and it did the trick ! Thank you man, thank you !

Comment: Write an answer and accept it.

Comment: I just did, I'll be able to accept it after two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `show` instead of `showAndWait` did the trick . Thanks to Sedrick Jefferson comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding ,you need to close current stage and open new stage.If you need to close stage A ,we can say current stage and open new stage ,we can say next stage ,you need  get window of your event and close it ,i mean window of **clickEvent**

```
 @FXML
private void ouiBtnClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("B.fxml"));

Stage stage = new Stage();
VBox mainPane = (VBox) loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
stage.setResizable(false);


    stage.show();
    nonBtnClick(event);


}

@FXML
private void nonBtnClick(ActionEvent event) {
  ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();//close currentstage
}
```

Comment: You just changed `showAndWait()` to `show()` which I stated in the answer, as for your last line, it does the same job as `nonBtnClick()`. Thank you though